# Install location for boost

Tags: macos, boost

I am trying to Install the boost through Mac Port using command 'sudo port install boost".It Installed but I wanted to know where it gets installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate boost
```

If you don't have locate working yet, you should enable it, it's often very useful.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/

And be aware that updatedb can take a lot of time (specially on the first call). But it's worth it if you don't want to use a recursive find

**Edit: I should have checked that before, but port actually contains a tool for that:**

http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.contents

Comment: Thanks @maresh It is working.One more question when we do sudo port install boost than where the files by default go ?

Comment: It depends on the package actually. But it is mostly the same directories like /lib/ /bin/ /var/ /etc/... I'm not really familiar with OSX directories layout.